# display multivalue attribute in gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a table `studentPhone` that looks like the following:

```
phone      studentID
2345678      1
0562436720   1
2254754      2
0546218611   2
```

I want to display its data in a gridView with sqlDataSource select query as:

```
SELECT phone, studentID FROM studentPhone WHERE (studentID IN (1))
```

but the gridView display only the firstPhone of the specified `studentID`. How can I solve that to display all phones for a specific ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT phone, studentID FROM studentPhone WHERE (studentID = 1 )
```

If you want to display all the phone number of one ID in a single column then you have to write a store procedure.
Example:

```
create table test1
( phone varchar(30),
   id int )

insert into test1(phone,id) values('2345678',1)
insert into test1(phone,id) values('0562436720',1)

Create Procedure getStudentsByID
@ID
AS
BEGIN
declare @test varchar(max)

select @test = ISNULL(@test+',','')+  test1.phone from test1 where test1.id = @ID
select @test
```

This will return you the comma separated list of all the phone numbers of the given ID.

Comment: you want that your gridview display both record for 1 ID in the same column separated  by comman. exp 2345678,0562436720 for ID 1 ?